# Problemas al mostrar datos en el index.jsp con ajax

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

tengo un código que no me resulta, necesito que el index.jsp se autorefresque con la consulta una bd desde servlet.

index.jsp

```
     <title>WP Não Fechado</title>

     <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!--  <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

      <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 70px;
            /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
       <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

 <div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
            <img src="img/bar.PNG">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ServletConsultData", //URL del servlet
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).each(function() {
                $('#tabla tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
                var row = $('#tabla tbody tr').last();
                var objeto = $(this);
                row.append('<td>' + objeto.propiedad + '</td>');
            });
        },
        dataType: "json",
   });
}, 10000);
```

})();

```
    <table id="tabla">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ac</th>
            <th>assmbl</th>
            <th>barcode</th>
            <th>wp name</th>
            <th>loc wp</th>
            <th>status wp</th>
            <th>wp sched end date</th>
            <th>flight no</th>
            <th>sched departure</th>
            <th>loc departure</th>
            <th>sched arrival</th>
            <th>loc arrival</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <td></td>
    </tbody>
```

```
</body>
```

ServletConsultData.java

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
    Consulta consulta = new Consulta();
    LinkedList ResultConsult = consulta.getDatos();

    if(!ResultConsult.isEmpty()){
        String json = new Gson().toJson(ResultConsult);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json); 
    }else{  
        response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");     
        processRequest(request, response);
     }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

app-ajax.js

```
$.get("/ServletConsultData", function(responseJson) {          // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response JSON...
    var $table = $("<table>").appendTo($("#somediv")); // Create HTML <table> element and append it to HTML DOM element with ID "somediv".
    $.each(responseJson, function(index, product) {    // Iterate over the JSON array.
        $("<tr>").appendTo($table)                     // Create HTML <tr> element, set its text content with currently iterated item and append it to the <table>.
            .append($("<td>").text(product.ac))        // Create HTML <td> element, set its text content with id of currently iterated product and append it to the <tr>.
       //     .append($("<td>").text(product.name))      // Create HTML <td> element, set its text content with name of currently iterated product and append it to the <tr>.
       //     .append($("<td>").text(product.price));    // Create HTML <td> element, set its text content with price of currently iterated product and append it to the <tr>.
    });
});
```

me muestra en siguiente error en el servlet

```
type Exception report
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
```

y en los js

```
type Status report
messageNot Found
description The requested resource is not available.
```

el resultado es 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más información? No resulta es muy genérico. ¿Tienes excepciones cuando se ejecuta la aplicación?

Comment: @MitsuGarcía no tengo excepciones, es todo lo que tengo en código lo que adjunte, soy nueva en el tema, es recién mi segundo proyecto

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste que la petición llegue al servlet? ¿No tienes errores de Javascript (puedes verlo en la consola del navegador)?

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta y anexa el error que tienes. Copia todo el rastreo de pila que te arroja (todo el texto rojo).

Comment: @MitsuGarcía editado :)

Comment: ¿Eso es todo el rastreo de pila (texto rojo) que te muestra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. En lugar de `window#setTimeout` usa `window#setInterval`:

   ```
   (function() {
       fetch(); // consulta inicial
       // esto se ejecutará cada 30s pero
       // con un delay inicial de 30s
       window.setInterval(function() {
          fetch();
       }, 30000);

       function fetch() {
           $.get('/ServletConsultData', function(data) {
               $(data).each(function() {
                   $('#tabla tbody').empty();
                   $('#tabla tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
                   let objeto = $(this)[0];
                   let row = $('#tabla tbody tr').last();
                   row.append(`<td>${objeto.ac}</td>`);
                   row.append(`<td>${objeto.assmbl}</td>`);
                   row.append(`<td>${objeto.flight_no}</td>`);
                   row.append(`<td>${objeto.loc_arrival}</td>`);
                   // lo mismo con las  demás propiedades
               });
           });
       }
   })();
   ```

   **Nota:** Esto se simplifica muchísimo si usas un framework como Angular. La añadidura de los objetos a la tabla sería automático.
2. ¿Por qué llamas a `processRequest` en `doGet`? Si la petición GET solo debe actualizar y devolver registros, no necesitas llamar a `processRequest` porque puede afectar el funcionamiento si tiene código.
3. Tu error es un `NullPointerException` como lo indica el rastreo de pila:

   ```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   ```

   Sin embargo, el rastreo que has colocado representa muy poca información. Así que, con el poco código que has puesto puede ser que:

   - `Consulta` no ha sido inicializado.
   - `ResultConsult` es probable que sea null.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41239/discussion-on-answer-by-mitsu-garcia-problemas-al-mostrar-datos-en-el-index-jsp).